# In an itemize environment, how can I align the item text (as opposed to the label) with the surrounding text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, itemize, enumitem

I have an unordered list, and I would like it such that the item text itself (as opposed to the label) aligns with the surrounding text. The image below is the example I am trying to emulate. How can I achieve this output?

[image]

Below is the code from which I am starting.

```
\section*{Education.}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Ph.D.
    \item M.S.
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Please provide an MWE, that we can see what you doing wrong.

Comment: Do you want the bullets in the left margin?

Comment: @Zarko Sorry, what is an MWE?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Zarko I have added LaTeX code illustrating the extent to which I am able to replicate the output. Is this what you mean by MWE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with `enumitem` very simply:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section*{Education}

\begin{itemize}[label=\llap{\textbullet\hskip0.2em}, wide=0pt, itemindent=0pt]
  \item Ph. D. Some text. Some more text. 
  \item M. Sc. 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
\begin{itemize}
\item [] Education
\item Ph.D 
\item M.Sc
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can accomplish the desired effect with [enumitem](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) by simply setting the left margin for the environment to `0pt`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{blindtext} % <- just for \blindtext

\begin{document}

\section*{Education.}

\blindtext

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0pt]
    \item Ph.D.
    \item M.S.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

---

The `enumitem` package defines a couple of keys that together allow you to customise the indentation of the items in a list environment, as that of their labels. The meaning of the lengths described by these keys is summarised by the following image/diagram, which I've taken from the package's [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).

[image: enumitem lengths overview]

You can probably guess what the keys for the horizontal lengths in this diagram are (just remove the `\`). (N.B. There's also `labelindent`, which is the total indentation of the label relative to the surrounding text, but it's calculated from the other lengths by default.) You can thus align the items with the surrounding text by simply setting `leftmargin=0pt` without affecting the separation between the item and its label.

If you don't want to change the indentation of all top level itemize environments in your document separetly by adding `[leftmargin=0pt]` to each of them, you can instead add the following to your preamble.

```
\setlist[itemize,1]{leftmargin=0pt}
```

Note that without the `itemize` option, also other types of list environments (`enumerate`, `description` or environments created using `\newlist`) would be affected, and that without the `1` nested `itemize` environments would indented in the same way. The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) for `enumitem` is worth a read if you want to customise these environments further.